# Launch default application for files with fzf

Tags: fzf

[fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) has some keybindings of which some are listed below as examples:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: `cd` into the selected directory
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: select a file

I want to add a keybiding so that I can launch the selected file with `fzf`, maybe using `xdg-open` or `mimeopen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
bind -x '"\C-o": file="$(fzf --height 40% --reverse)" && [ -f "$file" ] && xdg-open "$file"'
```

Restart your terminal, or run `source .bashrc`.
Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to open files directly with preferred application.

Comment: Thanks. Why does this not need `&` to be run asynchronously?

Comment: I added a `history -s xdg-open "$file"` before the actual command is run so that it's also added to history. Otherwise one misses out on history features, like using the up arrow to quickly re-run the last command---which is more efficient than using ctrl-o again.